# How to Display the Size of a file in Django

Tags: django

I have a pdf file in my media directory that i want users to download, the issue is that, how can i make the users see the size of the file so they are aware of the size of what they want to download.

Also, is it better to create a model for the pdf file as shown below in models.py?
What is the best approach to handle this. I need help.

models.py (this is not part of my code for now)

```
class PersonalStatement(models.Model):
    personal_statement = models.FileField(upload_to='personal_statement/')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

**views.py**

```
def personal_statement_download(request):
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    filename = 'Writing-a-Personal-Statement.pdf'
    filepath = BASE_DIR + '/media/personal_statement/' + filename
    path = open(filepath, 'rb')
    mime_type, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(filepath)
    response = HttpResponse(path, content_type=mime_type)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % filename
    return response
```

**urls.py**

```
path('personal_statement/download/', views.personal_statement_download,name='personal_statement_download'),
```

templates/index.html

```
<a href="{% url 'personal_statement_download'%}" class="applyRightContentContainerSubDownloadLink"> Download File &#8681;</a>
```

views.py for index.html

```
def home (request):
    return render(request, 'core/index.html')
```

Comment: The view itself is a bit odd, since it seems to just always download `'Writing-a-personal-statement.pdf`? Not the specific one to a user?

Comment: Yes, the same file will be downloaded by all users. what should i do please

Comment: Can you share the view that *renders* the `index.html`?

Comment: the view is empty, i only rendered the index.html. i did not do anything else

Comment: i have edited and added the index.html above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `personal_statement_download` makes not much sense: Django usually does *not* serve media files or static files. Indeed, these are typically served by the webserver like Nginx or Apache, since it is likely (a lot) more efficient and more secure.

But regardless, we can get the size of the file with:

```
import os
import os.path

from django.conf import settings


def home(request):
    filename = 'Writing-a-Personal-Statement.pdf'
    file_stats = os.stat(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, filename))
    file_size = file_stats.st_size
    return render(request, 'core/index.html', {'file_size': file_size})
```

then we can use the [**`|filesizeformat`** template filter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#filesizeformat) to format the filesize properly:

```
{% load static %}
<a href="{% get_media_prefix %}Writing-a-Personal-Statement.pdf" class="applyRightContentContainerSubDownloadLink">
   Download File &#8681; ({{ file_size|filesizeformat }})
</a>
```

by using `{% get_media_prefix %}` we can let the web server handle the file download. In debug mode, Django also serves media files, if you add this to the paths.

Comment: The file size showed,  i know that i will need Nginx in the production enviroment, but what will i add to make it downloadable on click in the development environment

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'os' for this:

```py
import os

file_name = "/Users/you/abcdef.txt"

file_stats = os.stat(file_name)

print(file_stats)
print(f'File Size in Bytes is {file_stats.st_size}')
print(f'File Size in MegaBytes is {file_stats.st_size / (1024 * 1024)}')
```

And to serve it to the front end, simply give it through your context like so:

```py
context = {
    "file_size": f"{file_stats.st_size / (1024 * 1024)} MB"
}
```

Source: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-get-file-size-in-python

EDIT:

Like @willeM_ Van Onsem said in his comment, you might want to change your filename to something like:

```py
filename = request.POST['chosen_file']
```